# Loop from separate dataframe to write .CSV in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apriori, arules

I'm trying to run an association rule for a different inputs and print the output in separate csv files. I would like to look up the model input from a separate dataframe and repeat the job until it has reached the last value.

Dataframe `CTVU`

```
MMGID_5    EMAIL
2341       1@email.x
50         1@email.x
311        1@email.x
2341       2@email.x
2387       2@email.x
57         2@email.x
2329       2@email.x
2026       3@email.x
650        3@email.x
2369       3@email.x
```

Here is the model

```
# Loading packages
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)

# Reading in data
CTVU <- read.csv("CTVU.csv", header = TRUE)
CTVU <- unique(CTVU[ , c(2,5) ])
CTVU <- as(split(CTVU[,"MMG5_ID"], CTVU[,"EMAIL"]), "transactions")

# model
rules<-sort(rules, by="confidence", decreasing=TRUE)
rules <- apriori(CTVU, parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.8,maxlen=3))
```

In instead of manually declaring `2341` in `appearance = list(default="rhs",lhs="2341")` and changing the name of the file each time a new new variable is declared, I would like to use a loop to run this processes x times.

```
rules<-apriori(data=CTVU, parameter=list(supp=0.001,conf = 0.01,minlen=2),
appearance = list(default="rhs",lhs="2341"),
control = list(verbose=F))
rules<-sort(rules, decreasing=TRUE,by="confidence")
inspect(rules[1:5])

# create rules into data.frame and write as CSV file
CTVR <- as(rules, "data.frame")
write.csv(CTVR, file = "2341_Basket.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Dataframe `MMGID` to look loop up from:

```
MMGID
2341       
50         
311
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Where does 289 come from?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik `289` is a value in the data.frame `MMGID_5` (sorry I didn't make that very clear - just updated the script). It's the value I want to replace with a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass a vector of values in loop and that vector would be the MMGID dataframe column that holds the values to be iterated on.

Below is a `lapply()` approach which will output corresponding CSVs and create a large list of underlying rules dfs. Also, I do not know name of that column as your post conflates the column name with dateframe name *MMGID* -fill in *Col* below as needed:

```
# ITERATE THROUGH MMGID COLUMN VALUES 
rules_dflist <- lapply(MMGID$Col, function(i) {

    rules<-apriori(data=CTVU, parameter=list(supp=0.001,conf = 0.01,minlen=2),
    appearance = list(default="rhs",lhs=as.character(i)),
    control = list(verbose=F))
    rules<-sort(rules, decreasing=TRUE,by="confidence")
    inspect(rules[1:5])

    # create rules into data.frame and write as CSV file
    CTVR <- as(rules, "data.frame")
    write.csv(CTVR, file = paste0(i,"_Basket.csv"), row.names = FALSE)
    return(CTVR)

})

# NAME EACH ELEMENT TO CORRESPONDING MMGID COL VALUE
rules_dflist <- setNames(rules_dflist, MMGID$Col)
```